# Full calendar in angular 4 events not bind at first time

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, angular5

I am trying it from last two-three days. I bind the `fullcalendar events` as follows but events are not reflected at first time on calendar didn't get why this happens the `bindEvents()` method called in `ngOnInIt()`

```
bindEvents() {
  this.availibiltyOptions['events'] = [];
  this.events.map((event) => {
   this.availibiltyOptions['events'].push(event);
})
```

OR

```
this.availibiltyOptions['events'] = this.events;
```

here is my HTML File:

```
<angular2-fullcalendar #calendar [options]="availibiltyOptions">
</angular2-fullcalendar>
```

Here is my TS file

```
availibiltyOptions: Object = {
eventClick: (event) => {
  this.eventClick(event);
},
dayClick: (event) => {
  this.daySelection(event);
},
dayRender: (date, cell) => {
  this.cellUpdation(date, cell);
},
columnFormat: 'dddd',
viewRender: (view, element) => {
  let viewSelectedMonth = 
   parseInt(moment(view.intervalStart['_i']).format('M'));
  if (this.availibilityMonth < viewSelectedMonth) {
    this.next(view, viewSelectedMonth);
  }
  else if (this.availibilityMonth > viewSelectedMonth) {
    this.prev(view, viewSelectedMonth);
  }
}
```

};

```
ngOnInit() {

//api-call
let fromDate ='2018-02-01' 
let toDate = '2018-03-01'
this.getAvailibilty(fromDate, toDate);
}

 //AJAX-CALL
getAvailibilty(fromDate, toDate, filters?) {
 this._loader.showLoader();
 this.calendarService.getAvailibilty(fromDate, toDate, 
  filters).subscribe((res: any) => {
  this._loader.hideLoader();
  const resBody = JSON.parse(res._body);
  this.events = this.createEvents(resBody.data.availability);
  this.bindEvents();
  if (resBody.data.salutation && resBody.data.name) {
    this.dentistOrPracticeName = resBody.data.salutation + ' ' + 
    resBody.data.name;
  } else {
    this.dentistOrPracticeName = resBody.data.name;
  }

   },
    (err) => {
    this._helper.errorHandling(err, this.vcr)
    this._loader.hideLoader();
  },
  () => {
    this._loader.hideLoader();
  });
  }
```

Now the problem is the events are not shown on calendar.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: Please provide package link also

Comment: @Kiwi Rupela did you solved the problem? I have the same thing, the events are not rendered until I clicked on the grid

Comment: @JadChahine I remember this happens due to the date i was sent is not in proper format. Please check your date

Comment: @KiwiRupela the problem is that at startup the events that I have doesn't appear but once I clicked anywhere in the grid they will be rendered correctly so the dates should be OK but there is something that let the events having their position as top/bottom/right/left = 0 always but after the first click they will take their original top/bottom/right/left values